# Intuition regarding connected versus simply connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm trying to understand the geometric intuition of connectedness versus simple connectedness. The lecture notes I'm working to state that connected essentially means "one whole piece," so a sphere and a torus qualified as connected. A sphere, but not a torus, is simply connected, and the reason given was something to the effect of "any closed loop on the sphere can be continuously deformed to a point."

I don't understand exactly what this means. I tried to imagine tying a knot in a string and shrinking it to what is small enough to qualify as a "point." It isn't clear to me where this comes from or exactly what it means. Could someone shed some light on this?
Many of the definitions I've looked up are too advanced for where I currently am at in studying topology, so I'm looking mainly for geometric intuition.

Comment: You write "A sphere, but not a torus, is connected", but in fact a sphere and a torus are both connected. Perhaps you meant "A sphere, but not a torus, is simply connected"?

Comment: Yes, I apologize. Let me fix that.

Comment: @JohnT: Connected = "one whole piece". Simply-connected = "... and no holes, please".

Comment: @Blue That makes more sense, though I'm still trying to understand the notion of "deforming to a point."

Comment: @JohnT An explicit example of a loop deforming to a point is the family of loops $\{ t \in (-\pi,\pi] \mapsto r e^{it} : r \in [0,1] \}$ in $\mathbb{C}$. (These are circles centered at the origin that collapse to the origin). If you consider $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ then the $r=0$ loop is not in the space so that $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is not simply connected.

Comment: Here's an alternative way to think about it; given any path with specific beginning and endpoints on the topological space (surface, plane, sphere, whatever), the topological space is simply connected if you can continuously deform that path into any other path that begins and ends at the same points. Notice that this includes loops (beginning = end)!

Comment: Imagine your body as a (very contorted) sphere. Put up a thumb and slip a small elastic band over it. you

Comment: @Blue: shouldn't that read "no **1-dimensional** holes"?

Comment: A space $X$ is simply connected, if any continuous mapping $f$ from a circle $S$ to $X$ can be extended to a continuous mapping $g$ to $X$ from the disc $D$ whose boundary is $S$. Here you think of $f$ as a closed loop and $g$ as a way of continuously deforming $f$ to $g(0)$ by shrinking the radius. If $X$ is the surface of a sphere, it may seem intuitively obvious to some that $X$ is simply connected, but the proof is far from trivial as $f$ can be very, very complicated, e.g., it might map $S$ onto $X$ (look into space-filling curves.

Comment: @RobArthan: *"shouldn't that read "no 1-dimensional holes"?"* Probably, but my intent was to appeal to a beginner's intuition.

Comment: @Blue: OK. I guess my point was that the notion of "hole"  doesn't give the right intuition (at least to me). If it helps the OP, then that's fine.